# Groovy mixin used with junit strange behavior

Tags: groovy, mixins

Having a simple class

```
class Bean {
String name
}
```

and a simple groovy test that make use of a mixin

```
import org.junit.Test

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue

class SimpleTest {

@Test
void testGroovyMixin() {
    Bean.mixin BeanCategory
    Bean b1 = new Bean(name: 'b1')
    Bean b2 = new Bean(name: 'b1')
    assertTrue b1 == b2
    assertTrue b1.equals(b2)
    assertEquals b1, b2 // fails here
}

@Category(Bean)
static class BeanCategory {
    boolean equals(Object obj) {
        Bean that = (Bean) obj
        this.name == that.name
    }
}
}
```

Why does it fail only when the equals method is called from within junit classes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `assertEquals` method in junit will be in Java and so will have no concept of metaclasses.

Therefore it will call the native equals method and miss the mixin